# LatLng Bounds contains() always returning false

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to check whether the user is in bounds of end location (a lat lng object) and even if the current location = end location, the contains function is always returning false. All coordinates are updating correctly. Am I using LatLngBounds incorrectly? Any idea how to fix it or an alternative to using Bounds?

```
protected void changeStep() throws JSONException {

    Log.i(TAG, " =========== changeStep ========= ");

    int i = 0;
    while (i < routes.size()) {

        //coordinates for end location
        Double latEndLoc = routes.get(i).endLocation.lat;
        Double lngEndLoc = routes.get(i).endLocation.lng;
        LatLng endLoc = new LatLng(latEndLoc,lngEndLoc);

        //setting bounds for end location
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(endLoc);
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

        Log.i("endLoc", endLoc.toString());
        Log.i("bounds center", bounds.getCenter().toString());
        Log.i("currentLoc", currentLocation.toString());


        //checking if users current location is within bounds of end location
            if (bounds.contains(currentLocation)) {

                Log.i(TAG, " =========== enteredIfBranch  ========= ");

                setText(i + 1);
                return;

            }


        i++;

    }

}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that you cant do anything with 1 point, how are you determining what you consider "in bounds" of the end point? You need at least 2 points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least two locations are required.

```
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    builder.include(somewhere);
    builder.include(endLoc);
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
```

Comment: Is there anyway to build bounds from a location? Or to get two points from a Location?

Comment: @SaritMafouda that does not even make sense what you just asked. It sounds like you are trying create some sort of geofence so maybe you should look at the geofence api https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: I should have clarified my question. I am creating a navigation app and I am trying to switch to the next direction step once the user reaches a certain location. However, I want the location to have a radius/bounds because the user won't always be on the exact latlng point. Looks like geofence may be what I need.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> builder.include(endLoc);
> ```

This is supposed to be "including()":

```
builder.including(endLoc);
```